# LINQ - exclude the filter when the value is NULL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am trying to see if there is any better way of writing the query below when there is an optional parameter (CountryId) which can be NULL

```
 public static IEnumerable<Game> GameByMatchingName(this IRepositoryAsync<Game> repository,  string searchCriteria, string countryId = null)
        {
            return repository
                .Queryable()
                .Where(x => (countryId != null ? x.CountryId == countryId : true) && x.Name.Contains(searchCriteria))
                .AsEnumerable();
        }
```

Ideally , I would like to exclude the criteria in the filter when CountryId is NULL.

-Alan-

Comment: @KhanhTO, wouldn't I be missing the search criteria check if the countryId is NOT NULL?. The condition is not either or but should ignore the check on countryId but still check the search criteria

Comment: @KhanhTO, does the above look for countryId(s) which are null in db? CountryId is FK in the db and it's  not a nullable field

Comment: Not sure if this works: `var query = repository.Queryable().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchCriteria));
if (countryId!=null) {
   query = query.Where(x => x.CountryId == countryId);
}

return query.AsEnumerable();`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<Game> GameByMatchingName(this IRepositoryAsync<Game> repository,  string searchCriteria, string countryId = null)
    {
        return repository
            .Queryable()
            .Where(x => (countryId == null) || (x.CountryId == countryId && x.Name.Contains(searchCriteria)).AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you build it in steps:

```
public static IEnumerable<Game> GameByMatchingName(this IRepositoryAsync<Game> repository,  string searchCriteria, string countryId = null)
    {
         var ret = repository
          .Queryable()
            .Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(searchCriteria));

          if (!(countrId == null))
          {
             ret = ret.Where(y=>y.CountryId == countryId )
          }
         return ret.AsEnumerable();;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on jquery datatable server side filtering. My solition is if variable null, compare with its own. Here with your codes :

```
 public static IEnumerable<Game> GameByMatchingName(this 
 IRepositoryAsync<Game> repository,  string searchCriteria, string countryId = null)
    {
        return repository
            .Queryable()
            .Where(x => ((countryId != null && x.CountryId == countryId) || (countryId == null && x.CountryId == x.CountryId)) && x.Name.Contains(searchCriteria))
            .AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

do not allow unnecessary parameters to occur for nothing in sql query

```
 public static IEnumerable<Game> GameByMatchingName(this IRepositoryAsync<Game> repository,  string searchCriteria, string countryId = null)
        {
            if(countryId == null)
            {
                return repository
                .Queryable()
                .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchCriteria))
                .AsEnumerable();
            }
            else {
                 return repository
                 .Queryable()
                 .Where(x => x.CountryId == countryId && x.Name.Contains(searchCriteria))
                 .AsEnumerable();
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: if need to use multiple variables with large db ?

Comment: @cancan things change in multiple variables,we need to talk by example

Answer (score 0):

**Necromancing:**

In general, if you favor overloading functions rather than default parameters, you can avoid unnecessary if/else statements:

```
private static IEnumerable<Game> GameByMatchingName(this IRepositoryAsync<Game> repository,  string searchCriteria, Func<Game, bool> filter) => repository
    .Queryable()
    .Where(x => filter(x) && x.Name.Contains(searchCriteria))
    .AsEnumerable();

public static IEnumerable<Game> GameByMatchingName(this IRepositoryAsync<Game> repository,  string searchCriteria) => repository
    .GameByMatchingName(searchCriteria, g => true);

public static IEnumerable<Game> GameByMatchingName(this IRepositoryAsync<Game> repository,  string searchCriteria, string countryId) => repository
    .GameByMatchingName(searchCriteria, g => g.CountryId == countryId);
```

The resulting code will always be cleaner and the intention will be easier to understand.  The maintenance developers will thank you for the reduction in cyclomatic complexity.